# How to combine three tables into a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

all with the same column headings and I would like to create one singular table from all three.

I'd also, if it is at all possible, like to create a trigger so that when one of these three source tables is edited, the change is copied into the new combined table.

I would normally do this as a view, however due to constraints on the STSrid, I need to create a table, not a view.

Edit* Right, this is a bit ridiculous but anyhow.

> I HAVE THREE TABLES
>
> THERE ARE NO DUPLICATES IN ANY OF THE THREE TABLES
>
> I WANT TO COMBINE THE THREE TABLES INTO ONE TABLE
>
> CAN SOMEONE HELP PROVIDE THE SAMPLE SQL CODE TO DO THIS
>
> ALSO IS IT POSSIBLE TO CREATE TRIGGERS SO THAT WHEN ONE OF THE THREE TABLES IS EDITED THE CHANGE IS PASSED TO THE COMBINED TABLE
>
> I CAN NOT CREATE A VIEW DUE TO THE FACT THAT THE COMBINED TABLE NEEDS TO HAVE A DIFFERENT STSrid TO THE SOURCE TABLES, CREATING A VIEW DOES NOT ALLOW ME TO DO THIS, NOR DOES AN INDEXED VIEW.

Edit* I Have Table A,Table B and Table C  all with columns ORN, Geometry and APP_NUMBER. All the information is different so

```
Table A (I'm not going to give an example geometry column)
ORN ID
123 14/0045/F
124 12/0002/X

Table B (I'm not going to give an example geometry column)
ORN ID
256 05/0005/D
989 12/0012/X

Table C (I'm not going to give an example geometry column)
ORN ID
043 13/0045/D
222 11/0002/A
```

I want one complete table of all info

```
Table D
ORN ID    
123 14/0045/F
124 12/0002/X
256 05/0005/D
989 12/0012/X
043 13/0045/D
222 11/0002/A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some sample data, desired output and what you have tried so far ?? read here to learn more about [`How to ask a question on Stackoverflow`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are there duplicate entries you need to take care of?

Comment: you have problem with creating table and trigger? you want help in what?

Comment: Apologies for not knowing the precise, correct way to submit something to this site. I do however think voting my post negatively is a bit rude considering I'm new to here. Hardly a welcome to the community

Comment: Why are these tables separate in the first place?  Why do they need to remain separate?  And you may want to simply consider a VIEW to union these tables together, rather than a duplication of all the data in yet another persisted table, with all the maintenance overheads that go with it..  `CREATE VIEW TableD AS SELECT * FROM TableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TableB UNION AL SELECT * FROM TableC`.  What are the constraints you refer to on `STSrid` and how do they need to be dealt with?

Comment: I can't create a view as I need to set a different spatial reference to the newly created table, one that differs from the original three tables, creating a view does not solve this for me as if I apply a new spatial reference to the view it is applied on to the three source tables too.

Comment: The tables are separate data sets - historic planning applications, tree applications, current planning applications hence the three different tables.

Comment: @SteveC81 - I think you need to me more specific with regards to that constraint.  Please could you give an example (in your question) of cases where this occurs, and what needs to happen.  Also, you mention that these tables are materially different, so in what way do they generalise to then be considered the same (to be kept in the same table)?  Are you taking a subset of the columns from each?  Will you require an additional column to differentiate their source?  etc, etc.

Comment: @SteveC81 - I'm sorry that you feel this is a bit ridiculous, but you haven't actually provided the information we need to answer your question.  You ***have*** stated that there is a constraint and elaborated partially in a previous comment, but it appears to have been clear to you, and not us.  With a concrete example of what you are dealing with, want as output, and possibly No Not want as output, we may be able to help.

Comment: @MatBailie Apologies if I didn't put things in clearly enough, however  I am new to this site and not skilled in the correct way of doing things. I felt after my first edit, where I gave examples of the type of data that should be sufficient. I do not feel it is necessary for me to explain why the tables are separate or why they will remain so. That is for me to deal with. I had also stated in my original comment that I could not create a view, so being asked to create one in the comments seems like my post hasn't been read properly.

Comment: @MatBailie I think I will go elsewhere for support as this isn't the most welcoming community. I admit fault at my badly phrased question, but I wasn't expecting the critique from members and the Spanish inquisition. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @SteveC81 - It's not the Spanish Inquisition, I've been asking pertinent questions in an attempt to help you.  I've left hundreds, maybe thousands of answers to help people.  I want to help you.  If you do not wish to answer my/our questions, then don't.  But we ask in order to help.  How you react to our asking for more information, in order to give better answers, that is your decision.  I've found SO the best source of answers for many topics, I urge you to consider how our attempts to help have been interpretted as an attack, even when we assure you that they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the creation of the table is a one time thing you can use a `select into` combined with a `union` like this:

```
select * into TableD from 
(
  select * from TableA
  union all
  select * from TableB
  union all
  select * from TableC
) UnionedTables
```

As for the trigger, it should be easy to set up a `after insert` trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
ON TableA
AFTER INSERT AS
insert TableD (columns...) select (columns...) from inserted
```

Obviously you will have to change the `columns...` to match your structure.

I haven't checked the syntax though so it might not be prefect and it could need some adjustment, but it should give you an idea I hope.

Answer (score 0):

If IDs are not duplicated it ill be easy to achieve it, in another case you can must add a OriginatedFrom column. You also can create a lot of instead off triggers (not only for insert but for delete and update) but that a lazy excuse for not refactoring the app.

Also you must pay attention for any reference for the data, since its a RELATIONAL model is likely to other tables are related to the table you are about to drop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for create the table D

```
 drop table D;
 Select * into D from (select * from A Union all select* from B Union all select * from C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its rather simple Just Create Table_D First

```
CREATE TABLE_D
(
ORN     INT,
ID      VARCHAR(20),
Column3 Datatype
)
GO
```

Use INSERT statement to  insert records into this table SELECTing and using UNION ALL operator from other three table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_D (ORN , ID, Column3)
SELECT ORN , ID, Column3
FROM Table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT ORN , ID, Column3
FROM Table_B
UNION ALL
SELECT ORN , ID, Column3
FROM Table_C
```

**Trigger**

You will need to create this trigger on all of the tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Insert_Table_A
ON TABLE_A
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO TABLE_D (ORN , ID, Column3)
   SELECT i.ORN , i.ID, i.Column3
   FROM Inserted i LEFT JOIN TABLE_D D
   ON i.ORN = D.ORN 
   WHERE D.ORN IS NULL
END
```

Read here to learn more about [`SQL Server Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: @SteveC81 Not a problem but remember triggers are known as "Silent Killers", They just do stuff sometimes when you even dont want them to do , so watch out, good luck pal :)

Comment: This doesn't deal with UPDATES or DELETEs to the underlying tables.

Comment: @MatBailie How much information you expect from one to provide in an answer ??  :)  , it is only a pointer in the right direction for rather larger Database Problem Solution .